# plot columns along multiple axes in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am trying to replicate the plot as in the image below:

[image]

All data is in this file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PbxTrX2NekN4i-2REInKcROdVnxX1xJr/view?usp=sharing

data looks like this:

[image]

I didn't get far at all. I know i will just `geom_col()`, but how do i get one plot per month per decade, all arranged like in the image? I can't find an example that looks alike neither.

```r
ggplot(
  data=sealeveldecade,aes(x=month)) + #
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_col(aes(y = mediansealevelmonth))+
  geom_col(aes(y = minsealevelmonth))+
  labs(x = "Month", y = "Sea level (cm) due to RH2000",title = "Median and maximum sea level per month during 1960−2009", subtitle = "Based on measurements every 24 hour per day")
```

Comment: Perhaps add `+ facet_grid(decades ~ month)` to your current `ggplot(..)` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create facets with your `decades` variables:

*Edited to arrange months chronologically*

```r
library(dplyr)

library(ggplot2)


df %>%
  mutate(month = factor(month, levels = month.abb)) %>%
  arrange(month) %>%
  ggplot(aes(month)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = mediansealevelmonth), fill = 'red') +
  geom_col(aes(y = minsealevelmonth), width = 0.6) +
  facet_wrap(~decades, ncol = 1) +
  labs(x = "Month", y = "Sea level (cm) due to RH2000",title = "Median and maximum sea level per month during 1960−2009", subtitle = "Based on measurements every 24 hour per day")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much!! So these are called facets! I'm new to this and sometimes i don't know the right term for what i am looking for :)